# Create custom script for DOM Manipulation

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm currently working on an Angular 2 Project where I have a menu that should be closable by a click on a button. Since this is not heavy at all, I would like to put it outside of Angular (without using a component for the menu).

But I'm not sure of how to do it, actually I've just put a simple javascript in my html header, but shouldn't I put it somewhere else?

Also, what the code should be? Using class, export something? Currently this is my code:

```
var toggleMenuButton = document.getElementById('open-close-sidebar');
var contentHolder = document.getElementById('main-content');
var menuHolder = document.getElementById('sidebar');
var menuIsVisible = true;

var updateVisibility = function() {
    contentHolder.className = menuIsVisible ? "minimised" : "extended";
    menuHolder.className = menuIsVisible ? "open" : "closed";
}

toggleMenuButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    menuIsVisible = !menuIsVisible;

    updateVisibility();
});
```

---

Finally moved to something with MenuComponent and a service, but I'm still encountering an issue.

MenuService.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class MenuService {
    isAvailable: boolean = true;
    isOpen: boolean = true; 
    mainClass: string = "minimised";
    sidebarClass: string = "open";

    updateClassName() {
        this.mainClass = this.isOpen ? "minimised" : "extended";
        this.sidebarClass = this.isOpen ? "open" : "closed";
    }

    toggleMenu(newState: boolean = !this.isOpen) {
        this.isOpen = newState;
        this.updateClassName();
    }
}
```

MenuComponent.ts

```
export class MenuComponent {
    constructor(private _menuService: MenuService) { }

    public isAvailable: boolean = this._menuService.isAvailable;
    public sidebarClass: string = this._menuService.sidebarClass;

    toggleMenu() {
        this._menuService.toggleMenu();
    }
}
```

MenuComponent.html

```
<div id="sidebar" [class]="sidebarClass" *ngIf="isAvailable">
...
<div id="open-close-sidebar"><a (click)="toggleMenu()"></a></div>
```

The action are rightly triggered, if I debug the value with console.log, the class name are right but it didn't change the value of the class. I thought the binding was automatic. And I still do not really understand how to change it. Do I have to use Emmit like AMagyar suggested?

Comment: Use the menuservice object to change the component's class: [class]="_menuService.sidebarClass"

Comment: Using a private value (`_menuService`) in a template will trigger AOT compilation errors. Something to remember for the future if you want to precompile your application

Comment: Of course, I was sure he would change that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantage of using `angular2` above your own implementation, greatly outweigh the marginal benefit in performance you will get from using plane JavaSccript. I suggest not going on this path.

If you however do want to continue with this, you should export a function and import and call this function inside the `ngAfterViewInit` of your `AppComponent`. The exported function should add the click `EventListener` and (**important**) set the `document.getElementById` variables. Because your script possibly won't be able to find those elements yet when it's loaded.

But let me emphasise once more, that `angular2` is optimised for exactly these tasks, and once you get more familiar with it, it will also be a lot easier to code it.

**update**

For inter component communication you should immediately think about a service. Just create a service which stores the menu state and add this to your global `ngModule` providers array. For instance:

```
export class MenuService {

    public get menuOpen(): boolean {
        return this._menuOpen;
    }   

    private _menuOpen: boolean;

    public openMenu() : void {
        this._menuOpen = true;
    }

    public closeMenu() : void {
        this._menuOpen = false;
    }

    public toggleMenu() : void {
        this._menuOpen = !this._menuOpen;
    }

}
```

You can then inject this service into your menu component and bind the classes `open/closed` and `minimized/extended` to the MenuService.menuOpen.

```
@Component({
   selector : 'menu'
   template : `
       <button (click)="menuService.toggleMenu()">click</button>
       <div id="open-close-sidebar" [class.open]="menuService.menuOpen"></div>
   `
})
export class MenuComponent {

    constructor(public menuService: MenuService){}

}
```

For other component you can use the same logic to see if the menu is open or closed

**update #2**

You have to use a getter to get the value from menuService. There is only one way binding:

```
export class MenuComponent {
    constructor(private _menuService: MenuService) { }

    public get isAvailable(): boolean {
        return this._menuService.isAvailable;
    }

    public get sidebarClass(): string {
        return this._menuService.sidebarClass;
    }

    toggleMenu() {
        this._menuService.toggleMenu();
    }
}
```

FYI, it's better practice to use `[class.open]` instead of a string class name. If you want to do it like that, it will only require minimal change in your current css.

Comment: The main reason of why I want to avoid using Angular component is the fact that my manipulation should be done over all the website and not just the "menu" component. 

The action will change the class on my menu (located in my menu component) and on my main content (located outside of the component). I don't know how to do it, and I'm not sure that this is the best way... Maybe by binding the service value directly...

Comment: I've updated my answer. But bottom line is the first line. If you want to communicate between components. Most likely you will need a service

Comment: He said Menu needs to change the 'main content' angular component, as I said in my solution the Menu component must be the 'main content's child or to communicate with parent through the service

Comment: Is it relevant in this case to have a MenuComponent or can I just put all the Html in the AppComponent and do everything in this (which will allow me to access content and menu in the same component). Nothing is done on the menu except this action, maybe it's a bit "overkill" to create a component just for that

Comment: @Sakuto If you can think of it as a single thing, in this case a `menu`. Then you should make a single component out of it. It might seem now like overkill, but requirements change over time, and so do projects and your view on the project. It's always advisable to compartmentalise your application. In the end result you will merge everything together into one bundle anyways, and for programming and readability reasons it's better to keep stuff like this separate in developement.

Comment: Updated the OP with an issue I encountered, if you could watch, thanks!

Comment: You have to use a getter. With primitives there is no binding. Ill update my answer

Comment: Got it working, many thanks to you! Now that I look my final code, my questions were really dumb. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Sakuto You're welcome. If you have some spare time, I would suggest reading the docs/guides/tutorial/advanced/cookbooks on [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/). This will give you a great insight in what best practice is, and how to take full advantage of the framework. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

> The main reason of why I want to avoid using Angular component is the
>   fact that my manipulation should be done over all the website and not
>   just the "menu" component.

You can create many components in Angular 2, it's easy and very practical.

> The action will change the class on my menu (located in my menu
>   component) and on my main content (located outside of the component).
>   I don't know how to do it, and I'm not sure that this is the best
>   way... Maybe by binding the service value directly... –

The main content can have a child that is the Menu itself.

[Take a look in this link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html). There are many solutions, one of them is to  "emit" the child changes to the parent.

If you need an example I can provide one quickly.

Comment: As stated in the other answer comment, I'm still wondering if it's relevant to create a component just for this.

Comment: You're no obligated to do it, but you already using it so it takes no effort to do. If you use it with angular, you can get the benefits of it's build to create an app more concise. Also you'll isolate the DOM handling to the component itself and not entire document.

Comment: Edited the OP with another question, if you don't mind taking a look!

Comment: I just took a look, check it out in your question